# AndEngine particle system

Tags: java, android, andengine

I would like to use AndEngine's particle system to create a splash(as in splashing water).

I have checked out the particle system example, but not really sure on what needs to be done to create a splash affect of water using the particle system.

Any idea's?

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ may have been a better choice?

Comment: Thanks, ill post there also. It seems like we have more user's that help out here though.

Comment: True, there is more traffic here. Not sure double posting or even linking would be the way to go. I'd see how it goes here, then get it migrated over if nothing happens on SO.

Comment: For most of my past AndEngine dev questions, ive gotten pretty good responses here. at gamedev i got none =/.

Comment: I can imagine. I would let it ride here and if you get nothing, eventually, flag it for moderator attention and ask for it to be migrated. Good luck! Just getting into AndEngine so I can't help yet.

Comment: Oh okay Good luck with your project! =)

Comment: @TryTryAgain The questions belongs here. gamedev.stackexchange.com is for questions usually about algorithms and game logics. This question is about a specific code, so it belongs here.

Comment: @Jong I thought so, but do you have any suggestions on this?

Comment: I never used the `ParticleSystem` class, but I can take a look at it and write an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any water splash simulation algorithms, so I'll do what I think, but you will have to modify to make it look real.

Water splash animation in 2D will create many small water drops from a single location, then send each one in a different direction with an initial velocity, then each water drop slows down and fades out.

Try this out:

```
public ParticleSystem createParticleSystem(final TextureRegion waterDropTextureRegion) {
    //X & Y for the particles to spawn at.
    final float particlesXSpawn = 400;
    final float particlesYSpawn = 300;

    //Max & min rate are the maximum particles per second and the minimum particles per second.
    final float maxRate = 10;
    final float minRate = 5;

    //This variable determines the maximum particles in the particle system.
    final int maxParticles = 100;

    //Particle emitter which will set all of the particles at a ertain point when they are initialized.
    final PointParticleEmitter pointParticleEmtitter = new PointParticleEmitter(particlesXSpawn, particlesYSpawn);

    //Creating the particle system.
    final ParticleSystem particleSystem = new ParticleSystem(pointParticleEmtitter, maxRate, minRate, maxParticles, waterDropTextureRegion);

    //And now, lets create the initiallizers and modifiers.
    //Velocity initiallizer - will pick a random velocity from -20 to 20 on the x & y axes. Play around with this value.
    particleSystem.addParticleInitializer(new VelocityInitializer(-20, 20, -20, 20));

    //Acceleration initializer - gives all the particles the earth gravity (so they accelerate down).
    particleSystem.addParticleInitializer(new GravityInitializer());

    //And now, adding an alpha modifier, so particles slowly fade out. This makes a particle go from alpha = 1 to alpha = 0 in 3 seconds, starting exactly when the particle is spawned.
    particleSystem.addParticleModifier(new AlphaModifier(1, 0, 0, 3));

    //Lastly, expire modifier. Make particles die after 3 seconds - their alpha reached 0.
    particleSystem.addParticleModifier(new ExpireModifier(3));  

    return particleSystem;
}
```

I haven't tested it, but I think it'd work. Try playing with the values to find an animation which looks reallistic.

The method receives an argument which is a ready texture region for each particle, in your case I guess that'd be a water drop.

After you call this method and get a `ParticleSystem`, just attach it to your scene:

```
final ParticleSystem particleSystem = createParticleSystem(...);
scene.attachChild(particleSystem);
```

Comment: Thanks jong ill try it out! Also should should the png just be a drop of water or how would that be?

Comment: Nice solution. Just noticed that the ParticleSystem max/minRate are inverted. Same with AlphaModifier's params. And with GLES2, the intializer classes have the infix Particle. I hope it helps, cheers.